# What library is best for a H264 video stream streamed from an RTSP Server?

Tags: c#, h.264, rtsp

Anyone know of an efficient, feature rich and C# .NET supported library for capturing H264 encoded video streamed from an RTSP server?

I'm developing a security application that needs to buffer video for a set amount of time (e.g. 30 seconds), and then when prompted (via an external trigger) record for *n* seconds after; so that what lead to the event and what happened after is captured.

So far I've found the LeadTools Multimedia SDK (which can buffer real time streams with pause/ play/fast forward/etc functionality), but its libraries and documentation for C# are lacking; with most of the features only fully available in C++.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After much research found that the LeadTool's Multimedia SDK library is the best option for this, although their documentation is heavily C++ based their customer support forum is excellent.

So for problems like this, seems best to either develop in C++ or purchase a professionally made library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Log each RTPPacket and then play it back when desired. If you took a little extra time you could even save it to a `rtpdump` file which would allow other plays to play it back.

Answer (score 0):

I've played a bit with the products from [StreamCoders](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/msnet.html) and they seems to work fairly well.

Comment: I've already tried the RTP.NET library they produced, it provided some good functionality but seemed very lacking in documentation. Are Streamcoders a reliable company? I couldn't find any reviews for their products or of the company itself, and so a little reluctant to buy from them