# Playing H264 in C# .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, video, .net-3.5, h.264

I am working on an existing application written on C#.NET 3.5.

I am looking for a free (open-source if it is possible) library, that allows to play h264 files.

Comment: Relevant [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686121/what-library-is-best-for-a-h264-video-stream-streamed-from-an-rtsp-server).

Comment: Does this work for you? http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnet/

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectShow and one of many media player controls if you install the appropriate h264 filters along with your app.

Another option is to use a library that has built in decoding, like VLC Dot Net
http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/